# Is this an open covering of $X$ which has no finite subcover?

Tags: general-topology

We have the set $X$ which is the union of the sets \begin{align*} & \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -2 \leq x \leq 2, -1 < y < 1\} \\ & \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -1 < x < 1, -2 \leq y \leq 2\}\end{align*}

They have drawn a sketch of $X$ which I think is wrong, it looks like a cross where the boundary on the top, bottom, left and right is not included. Wouldn't that sketch correspond to the set $X'$ where is the union of \begin{align*} & \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -2 < x < 2, -1 \leq y \leq 1\} \\ & \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -1 \leq x \leq 1, -2 < y < 2\}\end{align*}

Either way, I considered the last case which corresponds to the sketch. The set $X'$ is given the subspace topology with respect to what I can only assume is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ( it's not explicitly states which topology). The task is to find an open cover of $X'$ which does not have a finite subcover. I define the sets \begin{align*} A_n & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -1 \leq x \leq 1, -1 -\frac{1}{n} < y < 1+ \frac{1}{n}\} \\ B_n & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -1 - \frac{1}{n} < x < 1 + \frac{1}{n}, -1 \leq y \leq 1\} \end{align*} where $n = 2,3,...$

Let $A = \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty} A_n$ and $B = \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}B_n$. It seems to me that $A \cup B$ would be an open cover of $X'$ which does not have a finite subcover. In the case that I mistakenly assumed the sketch was correct instead of the equations, I believe I can modify $A_n$ and $B_n$ to still be an open cover which does not have a finite subcover. Am I correct? Are there any mistakes, or any ambiguity, in my arguments?

EDIT: I glossed over the part of the task regarding the subspace topology. It seems they define it as such "Let $T_X$ denote the subspace topology on $X$ with respect to $T_X$". Does this even make sense? Can you define a subspace topology with respect to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's a typo in your $A_n $  and it's  $-2\leq x\leq 2$ (similar typo in $B_n $).

Your cover admits the finite sub cover  $A_2,B_2$ (actually, $A_k,B_j $ for any choice of $k $ and $j $), although it seems you are working with $X $ and not $X'$. Technically, if you want to be strict with your subspace topology, they don't even belong to it.

For your $X'$, the natural open cover would be
$$
A_n=\{(x,y):\ -2+\frac1n <x <2-\frac1n,\ -1\leq y\leq1\},
$$

$$
B_n=\{(x,y):\ -1\leq x\leq1,\ -2+\frac1n <y <2-\frac1n\}.
$$

You want your intervals to be *smaller*, so that you need all of them to cover the "open" part.

Finally, I cannot make sense of your last paragraph. The subpace topology is obtained by intersecting all sets in the topology with your fixed set.

Comment: Thanks. I was so sure I didn't have a typo, but I'll have another look and come back with comment.